# Conditionally adding to Doctrine WHERE clause

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

How should one conditionally add constraints to the WHERE clause?  For instance, if `sex`, `maxAge`, and `minAge` is provided, the WHERE clause should be `WHERE sex=? AND maxAge<? AND minAge>?`, but if `maxAge` is not provided, it should be `WHERE sex=? AND minAge>?`  The logic below might work to determine whether `where()` or `andWhere()` is used, however, surely shouldn't be used.

```
<?php
// $qb instanceof QueryBuilder

$qb->select('u')
->from('User', 'u');

if(isset($param['sex'])) {
    $qb->where('u.sex = ?1')->setParameter(1, $param['sex']);
}

if(isset($param['maxAge'])) {
    if(isset($param['sex'])) {
        $qb->andWhere('u.age < ?2')->setParameter(2, $param['maxAge']);
    }
    else {
        $qb->where('u.age < ?2')->setParameter(2, $param['maxAge']);
    }
}

if(isset($param['minAge'])) {
    if(isset($param['sex'])|| isset($param['maxAge'])) {
        $qb->andWhere('u.age > ?3')->setParameter(3, $param['minAge']);
    }
    else {
        $qb->where('u.age > ?3')->setParameter(3, $param['minAge']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for all those conditional checks. Just use `andWhere` everywhere.

```
<?php
// $qb instanceof QueryBuilder

$qb->select('u')
    ->from('User', 'u');

if(isset($param['sex'])) {
    $qb->andWhere('u.sex = :sex')->setParameter('sex', $param['sex']);
}

if(isset($param['maxAge'])) {
    $qb->andWhere('u.age < :maxAge')->setParameter('maxAge', $param['maxAge']);
}

if(isset($param['minAge'])) {
    $qb->andWhere('u.age > :minAge')->setParameter('minAge', $param['minAge']);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't Doctrine complain that parameter `2` is not binded but parameter `3` is if `maxAge` is __not__ provided and `minAge` is?

Comment: Not sure since I don't use this syntax exactly. Instead of `?1` I use `:sex`. I'll modify my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks ehymel.  Didn't realize `andWhere` could be used without an initial `where`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can create a single string for `where`:

```
$whereArr = $whereParams = [];
foreach (['sex' => 'u.sex = :sex', 'maxAge' => 'u.age < :maxAge', 'minAge' => 'u.age > :minAge'] as $key => $clause) {
    if (isset($params[$key])) {
        $whereArr[] = $clause;
        $whereParams[':' . $key] = $params[$key];
    }
}

if ($whereArr) {
    $qb->where(implode(' and ', $whereArr))->setParameters($whereParams);
}
```

Comment: Thanks u_mulder.  I am actually going down a similar path and putting the constrains in an array.  They will, however, be wrapped in Doctrine's `expr` class.  Instead of manually building the query like you show, I will pass it as `$qb->expr()->andX(...$where)`.  Should work I think.

Answer (score 0):

I'll probably go with ehymel's answer, but the following should work.

```
<?php
// $qb instanceof QueryBuilder

$qb->select('u')
->from('User', 'u');

$where = [];

if(isset($param['sex'])) {
    $where[] = $qb->expr()->eq('sex', ':sex');
}

if(isset($param['maxAge'])) {
    $where[] = $qb->expr()->lte('maxAge', ':maxAge');
}

if(isset($param['minAge'])) {
    $where[] = $qb->expr()->gte('minAge', ':minAge');
}

if($where) {
    $params=array_intersect_key($params, array_flip('sex','minAge','maxAge'));
    $qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->andX(...$where))->setParameters($params);;
}
```